# Как выбрать значения из столбца вида {"key1":value1,"key2":value2, } в PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, json, парсер, oracle, plsql

Как выбрать значения из столбца, который выглядит так:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3", }
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Select values from column like {"key1":value1,"key2":value2, } in PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62451715) от участника [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13500493/andrey)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62451715

Answer (score 2):

Это выглядит как JSON. Если это действительно так, то такой пример покажет, как это сделать (заметьте, что нужен Oracle 12c или выше):

```
create table t (col varchar2 (100));
    
alter table t add constraint ch_json check (col is json);
    
insert into t values ('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3", }');
    
select json_value(col, '$.key1')as value, col from t;
```

Результат:

```
VALUE    COL                                                   
-------- ------------------------------------------------------
value1   {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3", }
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62456206) от участника [@Littlefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9097906/littlefoot)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с JSON в PL/SQL доступны, кроме некоторых SQL функций,
также [набор обьектных типов](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/pl-sql-object-types-for-json.html#GUID-C0C2A8C0-99BD-4770-9EA2-B7D53804FC18). Вот решение на чистом PL/SQL ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4962f9288fb748a01c72ce026f2ee37b)):

```
create or replace package arrpack as
    type pairr is record (key varchar2 (8), value varchar2 (8));
    type pairt is table of pairr;
    type jdoct is table of varchar2 (4000);
end;
/
var rc refcursor
declare
    jdoc arrpack.jdoct := 
        arrpack.jdoct ('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}');
    pairs arrpack.pairt := arrpack.pairt ();  
    keys json_key_list;
    jobj json_object_t;
begin 
    jobj := json_object_t (jdoc(1));
    keys := jobj.get_keys;
    pairs.extend (keys.count); 
    for ix in 1 .. keys.count loop
        pairs(ix) := arrpack.pairr (keys(ix), jobj.get_string (keys(ix)));
    end loop;
    open :rc for select * from table (pairs);
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
KEY      VALUE   
-------- --------
key1     value1  
key2     value2  
key3     value3
```